# Wordpress Permalink to specific blog posts, not current URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a loop on my homepage showing 3 recent blog posts, this is being included in from the footer. If I go elsewhere on the site though such as a different blog post, the 'the_permalink' is instead of grabbing the featured 3 blog post links, it's grabbing the link from the page your currently on.

These 3 blog posts will change as new ones are added so I cannot define that the link be only a specific blog post(s).

Here is the code showing the first blog post. Found within footer.php and therefore shows on each page.

```
            <div id="news-container-1">
                <?php
                // Create a variable to hold our custom Loop results
                $excludes  = array('4135');
                $frontpageposts = get_posts( array( 
                     'numberposts' => 1, // only the 3 latest posts
                     'post__not_in' => $excludes
                ) );

                // Create output only if we have results
                // Customize to suit your HTML markup
                if ( $frontpageposts ) { 

                     foreach ( $frontpageposts as $fppost ) { 
                          // setup postdata, so we can use template tags
                          setup_postdata($fppost);
                          ?>

                          <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
                               <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(1); ?>"><?php //the_title(); ?>Latest News #1</a></h4>
                               <div class="post-entry">
                                    <?php                                                
                                            $content = $post->post_content;
                                            $searchimages = '~<img [^>]* />~';

                                            /*Run preg_match_all to grab all the images and save the results in $pics*/

                                            preg_match_all( $searchimages, $content, $pics );

                                            // Check to see if we have at least 1 image
                                            $iNumberOfPics = count($pics[0]);

                                            if ( $iNumberOfPics > 0 ) { ?>
                                                <!-- GRAB THE IMAGE AND USE WHATEVER HTML YOU LIKE -->
                                                  <img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
                                            <?php }
                                    ?>
                                    <?php //the_excerpt(); ?>
                               </div>
                          </div>

                <?php }
                } 
                ?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_permalink()` doesn't have any parameters so remove the '1'.

You need to change the way you're setting up the posts. setup_postdata() is currently being used incorrectly.

```
if ( $frontpageposts ) { 
    global $post;

    foreach ( $frontpageposts as $post ) { 
        // setup postdata, so we can use template tags
        setup_postdata( $post );
```

Then at the end of your foreach  loop you need to reset the post object.

Change this:

```
<?php }
}
```

To this:

```
<?php }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```